# Convert an alphanumeric cell to the word Yes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with a column of alphanumeric values (xxxxxxx98746) and whenever this appears I want to change that cell to a "Yes". Not all rows in this column contain values, and I cannot hide this column as it will contain personal information. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Type "Yes" in a cell, then copy it. Select the column and paste. While this answers the question as asked, I have a feeling you will come up with a "yes, but...". If that feeling is correct, please take the time to [read this](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1462785/edit) to give us more info

Comment: Do the above procedure after filtering out empty rows

Comment: You mean to say that whenever in any cell you enter this `xxxxxxx98746` must be converted into `Yes` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this output for any numbers that you enter in a cell by creating a custom format. The Custom Format that you need to use is `#;#;#0;"Yes"`. Please check out the screenshot below:

The Steps that you need to follow are:

1. Right click on cell and click Format Cells.
2. In the Format Cells window, Click on **"Custom"** in the **Numbers** tab.
3. In the Type section, enter "`#;#;#0;"Yes"`".
4. Click OK.
5. If you want this to be repeated in multiple cells, you can use Format Painter.

**Note**: Please note that the above custom format **ONLY works with Text**. 
If you'd like it to work with **any numbers too**, then the custom format would be 
`"Yes";"Yes";"Yes";"Yes"`

[image: Custom Format]

Comment: Updated the answer above to work with any text/number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all values to "yes" except blank cells :

1. Select the column you want to modify
2. In "home" tab select "find & select" then "go to", "special" (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/find-and-select-cells-that-meet-specific-conditions-2d686424-6150-4015-a8e4-a5990f4d7e3a)
3. Select "constants" then press "OK"
4. Your "yes" then press CTRL+ENTER to fill it into all selected cells.

If you need to repeat it often and this process is still too long then do step 1 than start recording a macro and do the other steps.